# Is it possible to determine if the dynamic library finalization was called due to the process termination on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, dll

On Windows the DLLMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved) function is used when the process loads or unloads the dynamic library.
So when the DLL should be unloaded I can use lpvReserved parameter to determine if FreeLibrary was called or it is just a process termination was the reason of the DLL unloading.

But on Linux I have the destructor (e.g. the "fini" function) without any context.
And the question is, how could I determine on Linux if the library finalization was triggered due to the process termination but not by the manual library unloading or other reasons?

Comment: How would you "manually" unload a shared object? What "other reasons" do you have in mind? A shared object is "unloaded" by the OS if it's reference counter reached `0`. The reference counter is decreased by a call to `dlclose()`.

Comment: @alk, well, there are two cases: 1) dlclose was called in the application so the reference counter had reached 0 and the library was unloaded; 2) the process was terminated and the library was unloaded because of the process termination. And the question is how to distinguish these cases in the library destructor (or, is it even possible)?

Comment: I'd say case 2 is a special case of case 1 as it does also imply a call to `dlclose()` which then in turn could lead to the shared object being unloaded. It is not transparent to the OS why an application does not need a shared object anymore, will say: why it called `dlclose()`.

Comment: What you could do is add functionality to your shared object which allows the app (which uses the shared object) to tell the shared object that it is in the process of going down (for example via a handler registered using `atexit()` and/or a signal-handler, so the shared object could check for this in its destructor.